# MapView getMap() returns null on Lollipop

Tags: android, google-maps

Mapview.getmap going back empty under 19 version of Android ! MapView getMap() returns null on Lollipop. Version 22 also does not have a problem. Map opens and we can add markers. Why invoke the GetMap method returns null in the old version?

```
 public class AnaActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
             public static FragmentManager mFragmenManager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         ..
        mFragmenManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
    ...
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />
```

HaritaFragment.java

```
    public class HaritaFragment extends Fragment {

        GoogleMap mMap;
        MapView mMapView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_activity, container, false);

 mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
           hataGoster(e.getMessage());
        }
        mMap = mMapView.getMap(); // **** return null on LOLLIPOPS Version
       }
    }
```

map_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1) `MapView` as name suggests != `MapFragment`. 2) Use `getMapAsync` instead of `getMap` to avoid null. 3) `class` attribute can only be used on `view` (not `View` or any other) elements and it's an equivalent of element's name. So `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` element with `class` attribute is a total nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

MapsActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        mapFragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;
                setUpMap();
            }
        });

    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: i am using android.support.v4.app.Fragment. That's why the MapFragment is not being used